# Endless while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post some table rows into a database. I have created a while loop and it keeps posting my first HTML table row to the database. The desired behaviour is that every HTML table row is posted to the DB.

```
<?PHP
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","freoplanner");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$count=1;
$shiftDate='dp'.$count;
$shiftTime='shiftTime'.$count;
$shiftAantal='shiftAantal'.$count;
while(isset($_POST[$shiftDate]) && !empty($_POST[$shiftDate])){
    $sql="INSERT INTO shifts (datum, tijd, aantal)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[$shiftDate]','$_POST[$shiftTime]','$_POST[$shiftAantal]')";
    $count++;
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
header("location:shiftstoevoegen.php");
?>
```

Comment: While the word *while* can be used in the english language to effectively denote on of many alternatives at a single instance in time, this is not the case in programming languages. In programming languages, *while* has the effect of repeatedly checking whether a condition holds and repeatedly executing something until the condition no longer holds.

Comment: [Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialise the following inside the loop:

```
$shiftDate='dp'.$count;
$shiftTime='shiftTime'.$count;
$shiftAantal='shiftAantal'.$count;
```

currently, they will always be using `$count = 1`

Comment: So when the while loop is triggered again it won't update the variables outside of it?

Comment: No. You should re-initialize the variables again inside the loop body @NiekBakermans

Comment: Although you might think above did the trick don't take the irresponsible route and say "I have my answer" while you still have that huge security hole in your code.

Comment: I am fixing that as we speak via the link you commented.